# frequency table with several CALCULATED variables in R

Tags: r

**R Newbie** has a simple data table (DT) that has the number of households (NumHH) in several United States (Residences):

```
NumHH   Residence
6   AK
4   AL
7   AR
6   AZ
1   CA
2   CO
2   CT
1   AK
4   AL
6   AR
3   AZ
1   CA
6   CO
3   CT
5   AL
```

By using with(),

```
with(DT, table(NumHH, Residence))
```

I can get a table that's close to what I want:

```
     Residence
NumHH AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT
    1  1  0  0  0  2  0  0
    2  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
    3  0  0  0  1  0  0  1
    4  0  2  0  0  0  0  0
    5  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
    6  1  0  1  1  0  1  0
    7  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

but I need a table that provides the frequency of several ranges per residence.  The frequencies are calculated this way:

```
##Frequency of ranges per State
One <- DT$NumHH <=1                             ##Only 1 person/household
Two_Four <- ((DT$NumHH <=4) - (DT$NumHH <=1))   ##2 to 4 people in Household
OverFour <- DT$NumHH >4                         ##More than 4 people in HH
```

Ideally, the result would look like this:

```
            Residence
NumHH       AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT
  One       1  0  0  0  2  0  0
  Two_Four  0  2  0  1  0  1  2
  OverFour  1  1  2  1  0  1  0
```

I've tried:

1. `with()` - I am only able to do one range at a time with "with()", such as: 
   `with(DT, table (One, Residence))` - and that gives me a FALSE row and a TRUE row by state.
2. `data.frames` asks me to name each state ("AK", "AL", "AR", etc.), but `with()` already knows.
3. I have also tried `ddply`, but got a list of each calculation's (150 unlabeled rows in 4 columns - not the desired 3 labeled rows in 50 columns for each state), so I'm obviously not doing it right.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `?cut` to establish your groups before using `table`:

```
with(dat, table( NumHH=cut(NumHH, c(0,1,4,Inf), labels=c("1","2-4",">4")), Residence))
#     Residence
#NumHH AK AL AR AZ CA CO CT
#  1    1  0  0  0  2  0  0
#  2-4  0  2  0  1  0  1  2
#  >4   1  1  2  1  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks, @thelatemail. I like that you were able to keep it simple by using with(), however, this produces 'Error in cut.default : 'x' must be numeric.' As an R Newbie, I don't understand why 'NumHH' can be numeric in the earlier one-variable with(), but not when we break it up into intervals.

Comment: @uzay26 Your NumHH variable is not numeric I'm guessing. Convert it with as.numeric first.